# Finding the number of multiples of $4$ with $3$ digits

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

> How many multiples of $4$ with $3$ digits exist?

My teacher used this question as an example today, and then he showed us $3$ possible ways to find the answer. One of them was the following: $$\left\lfloor \frac{999}{4}\right \rfloor - \left\lfloor \frac{99}{4}\right \rfloor$$

But he didn't give any explanation on why this works. Why is this the number of multiples of $4$ with $3$ digits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $M, n$ be positive integers.  By the Division Algorithm, there exist integers $q, r$ with $0 \leq r < n$ such that $M = qn + r$.  Hence,
$$\frac{M}{n} = \frac{qn + r}{n} = q + \frac{r}{n}$$
By definition, $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is the largest integer less than or equal to $x$.
$$\left\lfloor \frac{M}{n} \right\rfloor = \left\lfloor q + \frac{r}{n} \right\rfloor = q$$
since $0 \leq r < n \implies 0 \leq \dfrac{r}{n} < 1$, so the largest integer less than or equal to $M/n$ is $q$.  Since $qn$ is the largest multiple of $n$ less than or equal to $M$,
$$\left\lfloor \frac{M}{n} \right\rfloor$$
is the number of positive integer multiples of $n$ less than or equal to $M$.

Therefore, the term
$$\left\lfloor \frac{999}{4} \right\rfloor$$
counts all positive integer multiples of $4$ less than or equal to $999$. Since these include one- and two-digit positive integer multiples of $4$, to find the number of three-digit positive integer multiples of $4$, we must subtract the
$$\left\lfloor \frac{99}{4} \right\rfloor$$
positive integer multiples of $4$ with fewer than three digits.

Answer (score 1):

The number of multiples of $n$, smaller than or equal to $M$, is always $\lfloor\frac{M}{n}\rfloor$.

Also, a number is a $3$ digit number if and only if it is smaller than $1000$ and it is not smaller than $100$.

Comment: Never heard of that. Why is that true?

Comment: @EduardoMagalhães Try listing all the multiples of $n$ up to $M$ for a couple of combinations of $n$ and $M$. For example, for $M=20$, take $n=2,3,4,5,6$, and notice what happens. Then try to generalize that.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{999}{4}$ includes all numbers divisible by 4 from 999 to 1.

The floor function is used as the number of numbers divisible cannot be a float.

Moreover, as 999 and 99 are not 0 mod 4, you cannot round up the float, but round down, sadly missing a number.

99 is the biggest 2 digit number and subtracting that only leaves

999 to 100, or in other words, all the 3-digit numbers.

Comment: I do not find your explanation clear at all.  As written, it is not correct.  You have not discussed the role of the floor function.

Comment: Okay I will change it.